# How to find the best match (set of options) among several sets of options?

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine a couple dozen services (sets of options), each of which contains a subset of all available options. I want to create a web form listing all possible options so that users can check the boxes for the options they want, then, after the form is submitted, return a report listing the services from best match to worst.

As an example, consider all the different TV services available- cable, satellite, streaming... how could I setup a page that allows a user to say, "out of 350 channels, these are the 10/20/35 that I actually watch" (check the checkboxes, submit the form, query the database...) then return a list of services that best covers the 10/20/35 specified requirements.

I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around the best way to go about this... how the data/tables would be structured, what the query would look like, etc. If someone could make some suggestions on how to best approach this, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Related: the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of thing you have to decide what 'best' means. Once you have done that the rest will fall into place.

So with your TV example, presumably each package offers a set of channels and you want the cheapest combination of packages that include all the channels you selected.

Simple enough, make a recursive tree search of all the packages, removing channels from the selection and adding up the price as you go. Order by total price and the first one is your answer!

However, what if there is one really cheap package that offers all but one of your channels, but that channel is not available by itself on other packages.

A real person might well want to see that at the top of the list, even though they would miss out on one of their *essential* channels.

It's this kind of thing you have to think through and get clear in your head. Once you are clear you can assign bonus points to these scenarios and order them accordingly

Here is a sample algorithm. You could do it *faster* in sql, but it would not scale well.

```
public List<List<Package>> BestMatch(
    IEnumerable<string> remainingChannels, 
    IEnumerable<Package> remainingPackages,
    IEnumerable<Package> results
    )
{
    var new_result = new List<List<Package>>();
    var rp = remainingPackages.Where(i => i.channels.Any(j => remainingChannels.Contains(j)));
    if(!rp.Any())
    {
        new_result.Add(results.ToList());
        return new_result;
    }

    foreach (var p in rp)
    {
        var rc = remainingChannels.Where(i => !p.channels.Contains(i));
        var new_rp = rp.Where(i => i != p);
        var r2 = new List<Package>();
        r2.AddRange(results);
        r2.Add(p);
        new_result.AddRange(BestMatch(rc, new_rp, r2));
    }

    return new_result;
}
```

Comment: `You could do it faster in sql, but it would not scale well.` -- That's not self-evident.  The kind of scaling limits you're talking about are quite a high bar, and there exist sql solutions like Hadoop that don't have such constraints.

Comment: @RobertHarvey its tagged for mysql, the standard approach would be some clever joins and sub selects. Also, as soon as you add in more than just the set comparison the SQL will get messy